# Fuse mounted Storage bucket showing 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, centos, google-cloud-storage, centos6, fuse

I have a google cloud project.
In that project. I have a VM instance.
I mounted uploads folder with Google Cloud Storage bucket using fuse.

While mounting I get an error like this,

```
Using mount point: /var/www/html/porject/app/webroot/uploads
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted
```

so i use sudo command
now i get reponse like this

```
Using mount point: /var/www/html/4thambit_v7/app/webroot/uploads
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
```

But i can't access the uploads folder, its showing 403 error (see image.)

[image]

ls -l command response like this

```
drwxrwxrwx.  1 root             root                     0 May  8 13:26 uploads
```

Anyone knows the correct steps to mount a folder in centos machine with Cloud Storage bucket.? if the gcs mount is successful. it will works similar to the local directory.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse), better support for the Google Cloud Storage FUSE is provided by the Community on [SERVERFAULT](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gcsfuse+google-cloud-platform). I will flag this inquiry to be moved to Serverfault.

Comment: This [GitHub link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) and this [GCP documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using) give well documented details about how to mount your Google Cloud Storage bucket using FUSE.

Comment: I later found that a similar case was opened in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/911600/while-accessing-fuse-mounted-storage-bucket-its-showing-403-forbidden-error) and the issue seems a permission error. The recommendation is to use run gcsfuse with the --foreground and --debug_fuse options. This will give a detailed information about the error.